# Delegates to generic operations where the generic type is unknown. How to create something like that?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

Suppose I have the following code.

```
static class Store<T> {
    public static T A;
    public static T B;
    public static T C;
}

public static class Store {
    public static Value A = new Value(<T>(v) => Store<T>.A = v); //just an example of what I want
    public static Value B = new Value(<T>(v) => Store<T>.B = v); //just an example of what I want
    public static Value C = new Value(SetC<T>);  //just an example of what I want

    public static void SetA<T>(T value) { Store<T>.A = value; }
    public static void SetB<T>(T value) { Store<T>.B = value; }
    public static void SetC<T>(T value) { Store<T>.C = value; }
}

public class Value {
    Action<T><T> _valueChanger; //just an example of what I want
    public Value(Action<T><T> valueChanger) { //just an example of what I want
        _valueChanger = valueChanger;
    }

    public void SetValue<T> (T value) {
        _valueChanger<T>(value); //just an example of what I want
    }
}
```

I want to write `Store.A.SetValue(42)` so that the value is saved to `Store<int>.A`. What can I write instead of the lines marked by "just an example of what I want" to make that happen? (I want to explore a solution that doesn't involve dictionaries or something similar)

**Rephrasing the question:**
I want to modify class `Value` (define some fields, write a constructor and write the method Value.SetValue(T value) ), then construct three different variables of type Value (A, B, C) in such a way that when I call `Store.A.SetValue(42)` the value `Store<int>.A` is changed to 42.

**Another variation of the classes:**

```
static class Holder<T> {
    T Value { get; set; }
}

static class Store2<T> {
    public static Holder<T> A = new Holder<T>();
    public static Holder<T> B = new Holder<T>();
    public static Holder<T> C = new Holder<T>();
}

public static class Store2 {
    public static Value A = new Value2(Store2<>.A); //just an example of what I want
    public static Value B = new Value2(Store2<>.B); //passing non-specific generic expression
    public static Value C = new Value3({TFree}() => Store2<TFree>.C); //just an example of what I want
}

public class Value2 { //Non-generic class!
    Holder{TFree}<TFree> _holder; //just an example of what I want
    public Value(Holder{TFree}<TFree> holder) { //just an example of what I want
        _holder = holder;
    }

    public void SetValue<T> (T value) {
        _holder{T}.Value = value; //just an example of what I want
    }
}

public class Value3 { //Non-generic class! (Another variation)
    Func{TFree}<Holder<TFree>> _holderFactory; //just an example of what I want

    public Value(Func{TFree}<Holder<TFree>> holderFactory) { //just an example of what I want
        _holderFactory = holderFactory;
    }

    public void SetValue<T> (T value) {
        Holder<T> holder = _holderFactory{T}(); //just an example of what I want
        holder.Value = value; 
    }
}
```

**Solution:**
An easy reflection-free and collection-free solution was found using the answers to another question ( [Emulating delegates with free generic type parameters in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878864/emulating-delegates-with-free-generic-type-parameters-in-c-sharp/12879105#12879105) and [Emulating delegates with free generic type parameters in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878864/emulating-delegates-with-free-generic-type-parameters-in-c-sharp/12926979#12926979)). The solution is [Delegates to generic operations where the generic type is unknown. How to create something like that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877550/delegates-to-generic-operations-where-the-generic-type-is-unknown-how-to-create/12967076#12967076).

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? I'm not getting what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be solvable. Mike-z gave me a nearly right solution for the delegate-to-generic-method problem ( [Emulating delegates with free generic type parameters in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878864/emulating-delegates-with-free-generic-type-parameters-in-c-sharp/12879105#12879105)) which I modified to be a full solution: ( [Emulating delegates with free generic type parameters in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878864/emulating-delegates-with-free-generic-type-parameters-in-c-sharp/12926979#12926979)).

The solution this question becomes easy too. Interfaces can contain generic methods and we can use the interface-valued variables to store links to generic methods without specifying concrete type arguments. The following code utilizes the `Store<T>` class without modifications and uses the `ISetter` interface and `ASetter`/`BSetter`/`CSetter` "closures" to hold references to different generic members. The `Value` class stores the references in a `ISetter`-typed variable and uses the generic member which the `_setter` links to once the type argument `T` becomes available.

```
public interface ISetter {
    void SetValue<T>(T value);
}

public static class Store {
    public static Value A = new Value(new ASetter());
    public static Value B = new Value(new BSetter());
    public static Value C = new Value(new CSetter());

    class ASetter : ISetter {
        public void SetValue<T>(T value) { Store<T>.A = value; }
    }
    class BSetter : ISetter {
        public void SetValue<T>(T value) { Store<T>.B = value; }
    }
    class CSetter : ISetter {
        public void SetValue<T>(T value) { Store<T>.C = value; }
    }
}

public class Value {
    ISetter _setter;

    public Value(ISetter setter) {
        _setter = setter;
    }

    public void SetValue<T> (T value) {
        _setter.SetValue<T>(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array to store the values and access them through a property using an index

```
public static class Store<T>
{
    public static readonly T[] Values = new T[3];
    public static T A { get { return Values[0]; } set { Values[0] = value; } }
    public static T B { get { return Values[1]; } set { Values[1] = value; } }
    public static T C { get { return Values[2]; } set { Values[2] = value; } }
}

public static class Store
{
    public static readonly Value A = new Value(0);
    public static readonly Value B = new Value(1);
    public static readonly Value C = new Value(2);
}

public class Value
{
    private int _index;

    public Value(int index)
    {
        _index = index;
    }

    public void SetValue<T>(T value)
    {
        Store<T>.Values[_index] = value;
    }

    public T GetValue<T>()
    {
        return Store<T>.Values[_index];
    }
}
```

Since the constructor of `Value` is not aware of any generic type parameter, you cannot have any reference to a specific `Store<T>`.

---

**UPDATE**

Be aware of the fact that a copy of `Store<T>` will be created for every distinct type argument that you supplied for `T`. See this example

```
Store.A.SetValue(42);
Store.A.SetValue("Douglas Adams");
Store.A.SetValue(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\"));
Store.A.SetValue(new List<int>());

var x1 = Store.A.GetValue<int>();           // --> 42
var x2 = Store.A.GetValue<string>();        // --> "Douglas Adams"
var x3 = Store.A.GetValue<DirectoryInfo>(); // --> DirectoryInfo{ C:\ }
var x4 = Store.A.GetValue<List<int>>();     // --> List<int>{ Count = 0 }
```

By using the debugger, you will see that four different values are stored in `A` at the same time! Of cause these are four differents `A's` that exist in four diffferent `Store<T>`.

Comment: Probably i don't get the question correctly but this is from question: `I want to explore a solution that doesn't involve dictionaries or something similar`

Comment: Yeah, you could use a switch-statement instead of an array; however, as far as I know, the C# compiler can decide to implement the switch-statement with a hash table, if the switch statement has enough cases. So a dictionary would be used anyway under the hood. You have to initialize the `Value` object with something not using a generic type parameter, since such a parameter is defined at the method level and is not known to the constructor. The only other possibility I see, is to use an if-else-if-chain, but this is not very elegant, if the store as many values.

Comment: Sadly this solution is what I called "solution that involves dictionaries or something similar".

Comment: I thought that maybe there is a solution that doesn't require delegates or dictionaries/arrays/collections at all. It's just that delegate-related idea was the only idea of the solution that came to me.

Comment: Example: Suppose that the Store<T>.A has a type of Holder<T>. Then we could pass the reference to Store<T>.A to the constructor of the Value object Store.A. But we cannot do it, because Value is not generic.

Comment: As you say, we cannot do it. An array has very little processing overhead compared to a dictionary and is very efficient. Any other solution involving delegates, switch statements, if-statements or the like would have a comparable execution time. A dictionary has a somewhat longer execution time, but a more or less constant execution time, that is independent of the size of the dictionary.

Comment: Olivier, Look at the new code using the "Holder<T>" class. It gives the idea of the static-typed solutions which don't use any delegates, collections or switches/conditionals. Still does not compile of course =)

Comment: Ark-kun, I know what you mean, but you cannot have a reference to a value holder of a `Store<T>` with an unkown generic paramter, since in reality a `Store<int>` and a `Store<string>` are two differents stores, i.e. you could store `42` and `"Douglas Adams"` at the same time in `Store<T>.A`,  because C# creates as many copies of this store as there are concrete type arguments for `T`.

Comment: >Be aware of the fact that a copy of Store<T> will be created for every distinct type argument that you supplied for T
This is exactly what I want to achieve. I want to create a store for different operators that act on different types.
Then I could write  

    operatorStore.Addition.SetHandler((int a, int b) => a + b);  
    operatorStore.Addition.SetHandler((Vector a, Vector b) => a.Add(b));  
and have the handlers stored in differnt appropriately typed stores - operatorStore<T1, T2, TResult>.  
Guess there is no other way than to use Dictionary<Tuple<Type, Type, Type>, Handler>...

Comment: I wish types were first-class citizens in .Net and Int32 was the same as typeof(Int32). Then I would pass and store types as easily as I pass and store values.

Comment: Sorry, but I've found an easy reflection-free and collection-free solution to this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877550/delegates-to-generic-operations-where-the-generic-type-is-unknown-how-to-create/12967076#12967076 .

Comment: You might be interested in this posts as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11701913/880990 and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/127736/41596