# How to "store" a type (not `Type` object) for future use?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, types

This is needed very rarely, but can still be useful sometimes.

Suppose there are stages. In the first stage you get access to some type `T`, but you cannot use it right now. Then, later, the second stage is performed and it has to do something involving the type `T` that was known in the first stage.
The `System.Type` objects are not a solution since they are very limited, compared to the real types. E.g. you cannot write `Type type = typeof(int); new List<type>()`.

Let's formalize the problem:

```
public static Something Store<T>() {
    //store T and return it
}

public static void Use(Something smth) {
    //do something with T (e.g. create a `List<T>` instance and pass it to Console.WriteLine)
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

**Update**:
An example use-case: Suppose we have two different independent algorithms. One selects an element data type (`int`/`float`/`decimal`, etc) and another selects a container type (`List<>`/`LinkedList<>`/`HashSet<>`/etc). There are many possible types of each and the whole possible set of types is not known. Now we need to write the central piece of code that creates the typed containers (e.g. `HashSet<decimal>`). We cannot put such code into either of the type-selection algorithms. What we want to do is to ask the algorithms to somehow store and return the selected types. This is typically done via type enumerations, `System.Type` objects etc. But I want a static strongly-typed compile-time solution.

Comment: You do know about `Type` class, and also reflection?

Comment: Do you know the type (what `T` is) in advance or are you trying to instantiate a type dynamically?

Comment: What do you mean you can't do `List<Type>`? That works fine (assuming you meant `Type` with a capital `T`).

Comment: @Dialecticus Yes, I know about `System.Type` (read the question).

Comment: @SiLo Suppose we are writing a library. We don't know the concrete `T` that the user will give us later. When the `Store<T>()` method is executed, it obviously has `T`. But we want to save it for future use.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen No. I definitely meant `type` - an instance of `System.Type` class, not the `System.Type` class itself.

Comment: @Ark-kun I'm a bit confused on why you are using a generic pattern `<T>` in this case instead of storing it as an `object`.

Comment: Sorry, then I'm not sure I follow. Generics work with types. There's no such thing as `List<foo>` unless `foo` is a type. The list itself, however, holds instances of `foo`. What you're apparently trying to do is not possible with anything in C#. It has nothing to do with `Type`.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Generics and constructors work with types. Let's call these types "alive types". I want to save an alive type to pass it through a non-generic context. One way to save a type is to use `typeof(T)` to create a `Type` object. But the `Type` object is not the same as type. It's a "dead type". It cannot be used for anything other than reflection. So `System.Type` is useless for me. What I want is a way to preserve a type in its alive state. And I found a way to do this seemingly impossible task via lambda expressions and generic methods: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20983343/1497385.

Comment: Sorry I still don't follow. I'm not familiar with the concept of alive types and it is certainly not a term used in the C# language specification.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen I thought I've defined them rather clear. "Alive" types are just normal types. The ones that you can use with generic types (`List<int>`, `List<T>`); the ones that you can use with `new` (`new TimeSpan()`, `new T()`). I used the term, because you seemed to confuse types and `System.Type` instances.

Comment: You're the one making up new language construct names :) I'm just trying to map what you're saying to the language specification. But lets just agree to disagree.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Well, the question doesn't have any fancy names in it. I've updated it to be even less ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C# doesn't allow storing types, we need to store the "ability to use the particular type".

First we need a way to express a type-dependent action (e.g. creating a `List<T>` instance and passing it to `Console.WriteLine`). Unfortunately .Net does not allow creating delegates for "non-specific" generic methods, but we can get similar functionality with interfaces, since they support generic methods (see [Emulating delegates with free generic type parameters in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878864/emulating-delegates-with-free-generic-type-parameters-in-c-sharp)).

```
interface IGenericAction {
    void Do<T>();
}

class MyGenericListAction : IGenericAction {
    public void Do<T>() {
        Console.WriteLine(new List<T>());
    }
}
```

We store the "ability to use the particular type to do some type-dependent action":

```
public static Action<IGenericAction> Store<T>() {
    return action => action.Do<T>(); //Returns a function that, given a type-dependent action (IGenericAction), invokes it with type T
}
```

Then we can use the stored type:

```
public static void Use(Action<IGenericAction> genericInvoker) {
    genericInvoker(new MyGenericListAction()); //genericInvoker will call MyGenericListAction.Do<T>() using the stored type T
}
```

Let's test it:

```
var storedType = TypeHelpers.Store<int>();
Use(storedType);
//System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] is printed on the console
```

Answer (score 0):

C# (or .NET in general) is strongly typed. This holds expecially for generics. If you create a  instance of a generic type, the type parameter is pinned at compile time. I am not hundred percent certain about it, but I think, the compile internally generates a whole new type for the generic with a certain type parameter. This renders it impossible storing the type and using it later on to create an instance of List. Anyway, when calling Store, you'll have to know T and from then on we're strongly typed. You could use

```
public static Something<T> Store<T>()
{
    //whatever
}
```

And then call

```
public static void Use<T>(Something<T> yourStoredSomething)
{
    yourStoredSomething.DoSomething();
}
```

Anyway, still you would not be able to use T dynamically. If we on the other hand did derive   the generic something from an interface

```
interface ISomething
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

we could do

```
public static ISomething Store<T>()
{
    return new Something<T>();
}
```

and with that something like the following would be possible:

```
ISomething mySomething = null;
if(t == "string")
{
    mySomething = Storer.Store<string>();
}
else if(t == "int")
{
    mySomething = Storer.Store<int>();
}
```

Please note that this is a solution to your problem, but probably not the best one. As I stated before, generics are stroingly typed and this is not the way they should be used. I'm misusing generics in a way I'd abhor and I provided the solution mainly for academic purposes, not to be used in a real program. Probably you should change your approach to the very problem you have, to achieve a better design.

Comment: "`Use<T>`" - this defeats the whole idea of storing. I wouldn't need saving the type if I had it available when I want to use it. "generics are strongly typed and this is not the way they should be used" - yes, what I want is a strongly-typed solution. I've found such solution - saving the type via lambdas and generic methods: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20983343/1497385