# Creating a non-static version of compiler-based "dictionary" where keys are types

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dictionary, compile-time

There is a very easy trick which creates a dictionary-like structure where keys are types.
The structure acts like a `Dictionary<Type, T?>` where keys are `Type` objects and values are instances of the corresponding types.

This  wonderful structure is as fast as just a variable or array since the "lookup" is only done once by the compiler/JITter and the proper value reference is compiled into your program.

```
    public static class MyDict<T> {
        public static T Value { get; set; }
    }
```

You can work with that structure like this:

```
MyDict<string>.Value = MyDict<int>.Value.ToString();
```

The problem is that this "dictionary" is global. The only way to create different dictionaries is to create different classes.

How can create a similar (fastest "lookup", no boxing) non-static structure? (Without code generation.)

Simply said: I want to have multiple `Dictionary<Type, object>`-like objects without lookup costs, casting and boxing.

Comment: Remove the static keywords?

Comment: I don't get it? What is the purpose of a class that stores a single value? Why not just use a simple variable...

Comment: I want a `Dictionary<Type, T?>` where keys are `Type` objects and values are instances of the corresponding types.

Comment: @JefferyKhan Then it would stop working. Each instance would be separate, so it would stop acting like a dictionary. Your suggestion is equivalent to replacing a dictionary with a (bunch of) single-value variables.

Comment: What you are probably looking for is Dictionary<Type, List<T>> but in a language in C# you can use a generic argument to do this because T must be known at compile time. You can do something like Dictionary<Type, List<object>> but that would require you to always down cast which in theory is not "type-safe".

Comment: @AmeenTayyebiJazayeri I want just a single value for type for dictionary, so no `List<T>`. I just want to have multiple `Dictionary<Type, object>` without lookup costs, casting and boxing.

Comment: @Ark-kun I'm not sure that's possible. Do you have a specific performance issue at play here, or is this a case of premature optimization?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair It's more of a beauty issue. I want to write `int a = 1; int b = 2; int c = a + b`, not `variableRepository.GetVariable("MyMethod", "a").SetValue(1); variableRepository.GetVariable("MyMethod", "b").SetValue(2); variableRepository.GetVariable("MyMethod", "c").SetValue(variableRepository.GetVariable("MyMethod", "a").GetValue() + variableRepository.GetVariable("MyMethod", "b").GetValue());`. I want "variables", not "lookups".

Comment: @Ark-kun Is Konstantin's answer satisfactory? It's an implementation of what we've been suggesting that you do.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Unfortunately, it doesn't satisfy me. It's alike the mentioned `Dictionary<Type, object>` solution (with a auto-casting method). The "API" is correct of course, but I want a different kind of answer to my probably impossible question.

Comment: @Ark-kun I doubt the exact implementation you want is possible in C#. You can obtain the syntax that you want easily as we have suggested with the wrapped dictionary and it will likely provide you with sufficient performance that you don't need to worry about it. With regards to your "beauty" issue, I'm not sure where the variables/names (like `a`, `b`, `c`, `MyMethod`) come into it as in your question, you only work with a statically declared `Value` property without any custom naming.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I doubt it too, but I some of my "impossible" generics-related puzzles turned out to be solvable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878864/emulating-delegates-with-free-generic-type-parameters-in-c-sharp/12926979#12926979
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877550/delegates-to-generic-operations-where-the-generic-type-is-unknown-how-to-create/12967076#12967076

Comment: @Ark-kun I don't see either of those as impossible. I'm going to add an edit to my post that is crazy, but if you really want to go for it...

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I've found the kind of solution that nearly satisfies me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063940/creating-a-non-static-version-of-compiler-based-dictionary-where-keys-are-type/14064329#14064329 (The resizing is extremely ugly though.)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair "I'm not sure where the variables/names (like a, b, c, MyMethod) come into it as in your question". The difference is that variables and methods are static typed and compile-time resolved while the dictionaries and other repositories are runtime resolved and often lose static type benefits.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair "Do you have a specific performance issue at play here, or is this a case of premature optimization?" I need this for a performance-critical part of the system: the operator repository. I need to store and lookup the arithmetic operation handlers for different type combinations. `public static MyMonad<T> operator +(MyMonad<T> a, MyMonad<T> b) {return new MyMonad<T>(Operators.Addition<T, T, T>.Handler(a, b)); } `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ark-kun is using generics to essentially generate unique types at compile time. With a generic type, any static members are unique to that specific closed generic type. This way it's processed as fast as a standard static member lookup.

The above usage is equivalent to something like this:

```
public static class MyDict_String 
{
    public static string Value { get; set; }
}

public static class MyDict_Int32
{
    public static int Value { get; set; }
}

MyDict_String.Value = MyDict_Int32.Value.ToString();
```

AFAIK, types are "static" (in that you can't define more than one that way) so I don't know of a way to cheat around this and maintain the same performance of a statically compiled member lookup.

Your best bet otherwise (I think) is to create a generic instance type that wraps its own dictionary that uses `System.Type` for its keys and `System.Object` for its values to which you have to perform boxing/casting when inserting/retrieving values.

EDIT: Here's a simple implementation wrapping a dictionary:

```
public class MyTypedDict
{
    private Dictionary<Type, object> Values = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public T Get<T>()
    {
        object untypedValue;
        if (Values.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out untypedValue))
            return (T)untypedValue;
        return default(T);
    }

    public void Set<T>(T value)
    {
        Values[typeof(T)] = value;
    }
}
```

Thinking about it more, it might be possible to achieve a more property-like syntax using an `ExpandoObject` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) through some tomfoolery, but I feel like this would be pretty abusive and I can only assume terribly prone to runtime errors. (plus it would afford you nothing at compile time)

EDITx2: If you really want to have *different sets of values*, you *could* nest it within another generic type:

```
public static class ValueSets<T>
{
    public static class MyDict<U>
    {
        public static U Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

With usage like:

```
ValueSets<int>.MyDict<string>.Value = "Hello ";
ValueSets<bool>.MyDict<string>.Value = "World!";

string helloworld = ValueSets<int>.MyDict<string>.Value + ValueSets<bool>.MyDict<string>.Value;
Console.WriteLine(helloworld);//Hello World!
```

But then the initial type `int` and `bool` in this case become "magical" and without meaning, plus you would need to provide a unique type per distinct set of values you'd like to use. Plus you could not pass it around and modify as an instance variable, rather it'd be statically accessible (so long as you have access to use the type `T`). So perhaps you could declare minimally visible types that are named with meaning and use those:

```
internal class MyFirstWords {}
internal class MySecondWords {}

ValueSets<MyFirstWords>.MyDict<string>.Value = "Hello ";
ValueSets<MySecondWords>.MyDict<string>.Value = "World!";

string helloworld = ValueSets<MyFirstWords>.MyDict<string>.Value + ValueSets<MySecondWords>.MyDict<string>.Value;
Console.WriteLine(helloworld);//Hello World!
```

Regardless, I think this is quite wacky and I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: EDITx2 is a very interesting solution. Since type-indexing is lookup-free, the double-indexing which I want can be accomplished with double type-indexing. (Although it's not very practical because of inability to create new types in runtime. Types can be created using reflection though...).

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach that extends the method described in the question:

```
public class TypeDict
{
    public T Get<T>()
    {
        return MyDict<T>.Values[this];
    }
    public void Set<T>(T value)
    {
        MyDict<T>.Values[this] = value;
    }
    private static class MyDict<T>
    {
        public static Dictionary<TypeDict, T> Values { get; private set; }

        static MyDict()
        {
            Values = new Dictionary<TypeDict, T>();
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can use the TypeDict like this:

```
void X()
{
    var a = new TypeDict();
    var b = new TypeDict();

    a.Set<int>(1);
    a.Set<double>(3.14);
    a.Set("Hello, world!");

    //Note that type inference allows us to omit the type argument
    b.Set(10);          
    b.Set(31.4);  
    b.Set("Hello, world, times ten!");

    Console.WriteLine(a.Get<int>());
    Console.WriteLine(a.Get<double>());
    Console.WriteLine(a.Get<string>());

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine(b.Get<int>());
    Console.WriteLine(b.Get<double>());
    Console.WriteLine(b.Get<string>());
}
```

Comment: It still has the dictionary lookup (another problem with such approaches (my answer included) is GC prevention). But the solution is very beautiful! I like the simplicity, the static type-indexing, the lack of casts and boxing and the `[this]` indexing.

Answer (score 1):

A more complicated version. Don't know if it's closer:

Define a generic dictionary:

```
public class MyDictionary<T>
{
    Dictionary<string, T> dict;

    public MyDictionary()
    {
        dict = new Dictionary<string, T>();
    }

    public T this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            if (dict.ContainsKey(name))
                return dict[name];
            else
                return default(T);//or throw
        }
        set
        {
            dict[name] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then a repository to store those dictionaries:

```
public class MyRepository
{
    List<object> repo;

    public MyRepository()
    {
        repo = new List<object>();
    }

    public void Add<T>(string name, T value)
    {
        if (!repo.OfType<MyDictionary<T>>().Any())
            repo.Add(new MyDictionary<T>());
        var dict = repo.OfType<MyDictionary<T>>().FirstOrDefault();
        dict[name] = value;
    }

    public T GetValue<T>(string name)
    {
        if (!repo.OfType<MyDictionary<T>>().Any())
            return default(T);//or throw
        else
        {
            var dict = repo.OfType<MyDictionary<T>>().FirstOrDefault();
            return dict[name];
        }
    }
}
```

And finally you may use this repository:

```
        MyRepository repo = new MyRepository();
        repo.Add("A", 1);
        repo.Add("B", 1);
        int i = repo.GetValue<int>("A") + repo.GetValue<int>("B");
```

In this example, there is `MyDictionary<T>` boxing to `object` is left.

From the other side, if your are working with some certain types you may not use thie repository class at all. But utilize separate dictionaties.

```
MyDictionary<int> intDict = new MyDictionary<int>();
intDict["A"] = 1;
intDict["B"] = 2;
int i = intDict["A"] + intDict["B"];
```

However it's the same as working with

```
Dictionary<string, int> intDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

So the `MyRepository` class may be edited to use `Dictionary<string, T>` instead of `MyDictionary<T>`.

Comment: Very close, but there is still a lookup. But your solution has hit me upon an idea. Maybe this is really solvable!

Answer (score 1):

@Konstantin's answer made me remember that there is actually a very fast lookup method - array indexing. This crude PoC code shows a variant of the required structure.

```
    public class TypeDictionary {
        static int _maxId = 0;
        int _id;

        static class Store<T>{
            internal static List<T> Values = new List<T>();
        }

        public TypeDictionary() {
            _id = _maxId++;
        }

        public T GetValue<T>() {
            return Store<T>.Values[_id];
        }

        public void SetValue<T>(T value) {
            while(Store<T>.Values.Count < _id) {
                Store<T>.Values.Add(default(T));
            }
            Store<T>.Values[_id] = value;
        } 
    }
```

This code can be used as follows:

```
        var dict1 = new TypeDictionary();
        dict1.SetValue("my string");
        string result = dict1.GetValue<string>();
```

The problem with this solution is it's memory usage caused by the repository being not sparse. This also makes first time value setting more expensive.

Comment: So you've swapped a `Dictionary` lookup with a `List` index lookup? How much performance do you need to squeeze out of this? Also mind you that by storing these values statically, the garbage collector will never collect them even once a particular instance of `TypeDictionary` is no longer referenced and removed from memory (perhaps a destructor can help with this)

Comment: Yes, I've replaced hash/Equals lookup with indexing. Array element is a closest thing to a variable. Thanks for the memory leak warning, didn't think about this problem (even though I spend this year preventing memory leaks in .Net (caused by events)). It's not that I'll actually use such code anywhere. The techniques, on the other hand, are valuable and I've learned something new. I've surveyed the possible solutions and analyzed the problems. My code will probably either stay with the static variant or use the `Dictionary<Type, object>`.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair "How much performance do you need to squeeze out of this?" I need this for a performance-critical part of the system: the operator repository. I need to store and lookup the arithmetic operation handlers for different type combinations. `public static MyMonad<T> operator +(MyMonad<T> a, MyMonad<T> b) { return new MyMonad<T>(Operators.Addition<T, T, T>.Handler(a, b)); } `

Comment: If one wants to use array indexing and doesn't mind casting to/from `Object`, I think it might be better for each object to hold an `Object[]`, and have the array index be a sequence number associated with the type [i.e. the first time an attempt is made to use a particular type, atomically read and increment the number of types used so far, store that value somewhere associated with the type].  Code which tried to access the information associated with a particular type would have to check the array size and might have to expand the array, but could otherwise be a direct array access.

Comment: " and have the array index be a sequence number associated with the type" Then we'd have a way to map `Type` to `int`. And the only way I know is a `Dictionary<Type, int>`.

Comment: " and have the array index be a sequence number associated with the type" But what is we reverse this? We'll have a global `T[]` and a sequence number associated with **object**. That's how I arrived to this answer.

Comment: Basically dictionary lookup is `.GetHashCode` + one or more array indexing operation. My TypeDictionary code is just a single array indexing operation. And the `MyDict<T>` or similar types have no runtime indexing operations at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class MyDictionary
{
    List<object> values;

    public MyDictionary()
    {
        values = new List<object>();
    }

    public T GetValue<T>()
    {
        return values.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public bool Add<T>(T value)
    {
        if (values.OfType<T>().Any())
            return false;
        else
        {
            values.Add(value);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
var md = new MyDictionary();
md.Add("!!!");
string s = md.GetValue<string>();
```

This class may store up to one value of type `T`. But there could corner cases with derived classes and interfaces I guess. You may check, if it suits your need, and probably modify it as you need, if it's close to what you need in general.

Comment: Well, I think it would be better implemented as `Dictionary<Type, object>` mentioned in the question. But it has the problems mentioned in the question: lookup and boxing (the casting is fixed).

Comment: @Ark-kun This still has casting from the `OfType<T>`. This is also not a `Dictionary` lookup: it will be up to `O(n)` where `n` is the number of types stored. It will also have issues with inheritance in the `Add` method.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is impossible in C#. The language does not support a container that could store multiple objects of different types yet provides a look up method that does not involve casting, boxing or unboxing. You could accomplish something like this with macros in C++, or via a language like javascript where the structure of types can be changed at run-time.

Comment: If you look at the answers, you'll see that there are couple of such containers mentioned. There is the original static "dictionary" (we can create multiple "instances" of it) http://stackoverflow.com/q/14063940/1497385. There is also a "double-type-indexed" "dictionary" http://stackoverflow.com/a/14064051/1497385. These ones don't have any lookup. There is a container with the "array-indexing" lookup http://stackoverflow.com/a/14064329/1497385. Lastly, there is a beautiful dictionary-based solution that doesn't have casting or boxing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14064463/1497385.

Answer (score 0):

The usage case you are describing fits quite closely with the purpose for which `ConditionalWeakTable<TKey,TValue>` was added to .NET 4.0.  For the purpose you describe, you would include such a table in a static generic class, and then for every class object that's supposed to contain a reference to an item of a particular type you would store into that type's table a reference to object that's supposed to contain the item along with either a reference to the item, or else a reference to a simple item-holder object (note that entries in `ConditionalWeakTable` will evaporate when an object ceases to exist, but are otherwise immutable, so if you want a mutable association you'll need to create an object to hold it).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know about the `ConditionalWeakTable` and even `DependentHandl`, but I don't think it's relevant to my question. There are two types of bindings - compile-time and runtime. Accessing a variable can be thought as a type of binding. There is a difference between `a = 1` (compile-time) and `dict["a"] = 1`(runtime indexing). The "dictionary" in my example is completely compile-time bound. `MyDict<int>.Value = 1` is the same as `int MyDict_int_Value = 1`.

Comment: `MyDict<int>.Value = 1` would effectively execute as `MyDictionaryHelper<int>.theTable.GetValue(MyDict, (x)=> new int[0])[0] = 1`, assuming `internal static class MyDictionaryHelper<T> { internal ConditionalWeakTable<MyDictType,T[]> theTable;}`.  Semantically, the code would behave as though the items were stored in `MyDict`, and everything about the code would be fully type-safe [if desired, one could define an value holder class instead of using an array].  What more do you want?

Comment: Semantically the code using any dictionary type is the same. Like the second code block from http://stackoverflow.com/a/14064051/1497385 - a simple structure based on `Dictionary<Type, object>`. I don't see the difference here. The difference between `MyDict` `Dictionary`/`ConditionalWeakTable` is the ultra-fast compile-time indexing (no indexing at all).

Comment: @Ark-kun: The code using `ConditionalWeakTable` is fully type-safe, while a `Dictionary<Type, Object>` is not.  What you are seeking fundamentally is to retrieve something based upon a combination of an object reference and type, so neither the fast ways to retrieve a static object of a generic type, nor the fast ways to retrieve a known individual field of an object, are going to be applicable.  It would be possible to have `internal static class Fetchers<TDummy> { public class Holders<T> { static T Value; } public static T GetValue<TValue>() {return Holders<T>.Value;} }`, and...

Comment: @Ark-kun: ...have every instance of `MyDict` create a different dummy type which could be used for the lookup [the code above isn't quite right], which would in theory eliminate the need for run-time indexing.  In practice, torturing the type system in such fashion would almost certainly make things slower rather than faster.  The .NET type system can handle the run-time creation of thousands of types, but will get more and more bogged down as the number of types increases.

Comment: Yes, creating dynamic types just for indexing is bad. But there are other solutions. Basically dictionary lookup is `.GetHashCode` + one or more array indexing. My solution (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14064329/1497385) although very crude, eliminates the `.GetHashCode` part by using the plain array indexing.

Comment: Instance field is "indexed" by object reference.
Instance array field is "indexed" by object reference, then by integer index.
Instance `Dictionary<Type, Object>` field in a non-generic type is "indexed" by object reference, then hash-indexed by type.

Instance field in a generic type is "indexed" by typed object reference.
Instance array field in a generic type is "indexed" by typed object reference, then by integer index.
Instance `Dictionary<TObj, T>` field in a generic type is "indexed" by typed object reference, then hash-indexed by object reference.

Comment: Static field in a generic type is "indexed" by type.
Static array field in a generic type is "indexed" by type, then by integer index.
Static `Dictionary<TObj, T>` field in a generic type is "indexed" by type, then hash-indexed by object reference.

Comment: And what I want is a "structure indexed by object reference, then by type".

Comment: A very close dead-end: a static (VB) variable inside a generic instance method of a non-generic type: `Public Sub SetValue(Of T)(value As T)
        Static variable As T = value
    End Sub`, but the compiler specifically forbids that: `Local variables within generic methods cannot be declared 'Static'.`

Comment: @Ark-kun: A compiler construct which is forbidden because it would require the existence of a data structure that doesn't exist in .NET may "seem" close, but I don't know that it really is.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @phoog's example with @supercat's suggestion

```
public class TypeDict
{
    public T Get<T>() where T : class
    {
        T value;
        InnerDict<T>.Values.TryGetValue(this, out value);
        return value;
    }
    public void Set<T>(T value) where T : class
    {
        var cwt = InnerDict<T>.Values;
        // lock+remove+add https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/4545
        lock (cwt)
        {
            cwt.Remove(this);
            cwt.Add(this, value);
        }
    }
    private static class InnerDict<T> where T : class
    {
        public static ConditionalWeakTable<TypeDict, T> Values { get; private set; }

        static InnerDict()
        {
            Values = new ConditionalWeakTable<TypeDict, T>();
        }
    }
}
```